# Here Fleet Telematics (CalculaterouteAPI) response error

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

Here Fleet Telematics API - Response Error

Trying to use calculateroute api for the request:
https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?apikey=&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&length=100&height=100&capacity=100&departure=2022-06-17T08:35:58&waypoint0=-34.93522,138.53637&waypoint1=-34.92585,138.5998;opening:2022-06-17T08:35:58;closing:2022-06-17T17:00:00;sort&waypoint2=-34.94613,138.58924;opening:2022-06-17T13:35:37;closing:2022-06-17T17:00:00;sort&waypoint3=-34.86227,138.58331;opening:2022-06-17T14:06:18;closing:2022-06-17T17:00:00;sort&waypoint4=-34.93522,138.53637

But got the bellow error:
"Couldn't reach way point 4 (start links -777941868 777941868  dest links -777941868 777941868 ), closest link to destination reached: -777941868 at -34.93523/138.53602"

Regarding the response [HereAPI - Can't reach waypoints requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272757/hereapi-cant-reach-waypoints-requested), I used **&ignoreWaypointVehicleRestriction=100000** and **&traverseGates=true** but got the same error and Here is unable to calculate it.

Is there any solution for getting result without error?

Comment: https://www.here.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

we have a parameter called "proximity" you can check in our API Reference in the documentation, this parameter is a circular search area specified by center latitude, longitude [WGS84 degrees], and radius [meter].

All geometries overlapping this circle will be returned, sorted by distance, closest first. Example: proximity=47.731,7.5549,100 Multiple coordinate pairs can be passed as a semicolon-separated list. For each of them, the layer_ids list is searched. If each coordinate pair is explored in a different set of layers, layer_ids contains a semicolon-separated list of (comma-separated list of) layers.

This parameter will do the trick.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html